# Is there any any relationship between efficiency and confidence interval width?

Tags: self-study

I do not understand the concept of the efficiency of a statistical test.

Is there some relationship to confidence interval width?

For example, suppose I have two statistical tests, A and B. Test A produces very wide confidence intervals, and test B produces very narrow confidence intervals. Does this have anything to do with the efficiency of the test?

Answer (score 4):

Efficiency refers to the statistic and its distribution.  In your case with two distributions we should be estimating the same parameter and a fair comparison require an equal sample size.  Assuming this setup, the more efficient estimator will tend to have a smaller variance. So given the 1-1 correspondence between confidence intervals and hypothesis tests, the more efficient estimator should tend to have a shorter confidence interval.   I use the term "tend" because in any given case with finite sample size, it is possible for the more efficient estimator to have a larger variance.  The chance of this opposite occurrence becomes small as the sample size gets large.

Comment: +1.  Good summary with excellent qualifying comments.  Since answering a question can be taken as *prima facie* evidence that it is sufficiently clear and has some interest or importance, might I suggest making a general practice of upvoting questions one has answered?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the compliment. When I see others give good (correct an well-written answers I do sometimes use the upvote.  My hesitation is that I think I have daily limits and there are so many questions to potentially go through.

Comment: @whuber I have noticed that now that I have new privileges that I share with moderators I am not sure what to do to make use of them.

Comment: Are you able to use the [site chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18/ten-fold)?  If so, that would be a great place to discuss ways to use the site.

Comment: @whuber I tried meta CrossValidated and I think I was able to do some of these thing there.  I have used the chat room when there are excessive comments in a post but I didn't think it had anything to do with some of these moderating actions.